# Reporting portlet for Liferay CE(Community Edition)?

Tags: report, reporting, liferay, portlet, liferay-6

Is there Any Report functionality in liferay?i have goggled for this but what i can found is there's only reporting functionality for EE(enterprise edition) but i am using CE(community edition) so anyone know or have implemented reporting functionality or any readymade portlet for reporting in liferay?

I know About Jasper Report but am not much technically sound to java so hard to integrate in my liferay so before go for that i want to be sure that is there any reporting feature provided already in liferay CE?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

i have implemented jasper reports in ma liferay portlet..so..thats the solution to my question

Comment: At-least you should have included some of the useful information regarding Jasper reports integration in Liferay.

Answer (score 0):

This [portlet application](http://www.visioneo.org/) works with Liferay CE,  it runs BIRT reports and has a free edition